# Python. Change numeric data into categorical

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

i have got some dataset with column that is consist of only numeric variables and new column which i have to fill with categorical data that is connected with this variables ,let's name this column just "new_data"

```
0      12.6
1       6.9
2      24.6
3      10.9
4      27.8
```

How I can transform it to categorical (for ex. if data[i]<=17 then new_data[i]="low",if data[i]>17 and data[i]<24 then new_data[i]="average" and if data[i]>24 then new_data[i]="high") with the help of special functions from sklearn or pandas without using loops.
thank you

Comment: What's `a`/`b`/`amd`/`c`? Please improve clarity of your question.

Comment: @thushv89 i have edited my question, please look through

Comment: Add a new column based on that compound condition.

Comment: @thushv89 but i want to use some function from sklearn or pandas

Comment: @thushv89 also may be you know how i can use a lambda there